# I keep getting error messages when I try to add a page with Plone 4.3(pastie.org/pasties/8060438/text)

Tags: plone

I'm using Plone 4.3 on a Mac mini running Lion (OX10.7.5) and every time  I try to add a page I get a very long error message (pastie.org/pasties/8060438/text). I can add images as well as add folders and collections, but I can't seem to add any pages. Thank you for

```
Traceback (innermost last):

Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
Module Products.CMFPlone.FactoryTool, line 473, in __call__
Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
Module Products.CMFFormController.FSControllerPageTemplate, line 91, in __call__
Module Products.CMFFormController.BaseControllerPageTemplate, line 31, in _call
Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 322, in __call__
Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 359, in _bindAndExec
Module Products.CMFCore.FSPageTemplate, line 237, in _exec
Module Products.CMFCore.FSPageTemplate, line 177, in pt_render
Module Products.PageTemplates.PageTemplate, line 79, in pt_render
Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 132, in pt_render
Warning: Macro expansion failed
Warning: <type 'exceptions.KeyError'>: 'macro'
Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 240, in __call__
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 271, in __call__
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 888, in do_useMacro
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 888, in do_useMacro
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 954, in do_defineSlot
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 858, in do_defineMacro
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 954, in do_defineSlot
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 946, in do_defineSlot
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 858, in do_defineMacro
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 888, in do_useMacro
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 852, in do_condition
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 954, in do_defineSlot
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 852, in do_condition
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 821, in do_loop_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 522, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 821, in do_loop_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 888, in do_useMacro
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 888, in do_useMacro
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 852, in do_condition
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 852, in do_condition
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 946, in do_defineSlot
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 888, in do_useMacro
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 888, in do_useMacro
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 888, in do_useMacro
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 583, in do_setLocal_tal
Module zope.tales.tales, line 696, in evaluate
URL: file:/Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.TinyMCE-1.3.3-py2.7.egg/Products/TinyMCE/skins/tinymce/tinymce_wysiwyg_support.pt
Line 6, Column 2
Expression: <PythonExpr configuration_method(field=field)>
Names:
{'container': <PloneSite at /CMLIT010>,
 'context': <ATDocument at /CMLIT010/chapter-12-files/portal_factory/Document/document.2013-06-19.0191801348 used for /CMLIT010/chapter-12-files>,
 'default': <object object at 0x10a0ceb30>,
 'here': <ATDocument at /CMLIT010/chapter-12-files/portal_factory/Document/document.2013-06-19.0191801348 used for /CMLIT010/chapter-12-files>,
 'loop': {u'field': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.PathIterator object at 0x10f852f10>,
          u'fieldset': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.PathIterator object at 0x10f9f6cd0>},
 'nothing': None,
 'options': {'args': (),
             'state': <Products.CMFFormController.ControllerState.ControllerState object at 0x10f29e210>},
 'repeat': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.SafeMapping object at 0x10f9b7f70>,
 'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=http://localhost:8080/CMLIT010/chapter-12-files/portal_factory/Document/document.2013-06-19.0191801348/atct_edit>,
 'root': <Application at >,
 'template': <FSControllerPageTemplate at /CMLIT010/atct_edit used for /CMLIT010/chapter-12-files/portal_factory/Document/document.2013-06-19.0191801348>,
 'traverse_subpath': [],
 'user': <PropertiedUser 'admin'>}
Module Products.PageTemplates.ZRPythonExpr, line 48, in __call__
__traceback_info__: configuration_method(field=field)
Module PythonExpr, line 1, in <expression>
Module Products.TinyMCE.browser.browser, line 127, in jsonConfiguration
Module Products.TinyMCE.utility, line 951, in getConfiguration
AttributeError: thumbnail_size
```

Comment: This sounds more like a bug report than a question. Open a ticket at https://dev.plone.org/newticket

Comment: @user2502668: Did you file a ticket? Respectively, did this happen with a freshly installed Plone-site?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error installing a basic 4.3.1 site. The installer couldn't grab a couple of packages during the install (mostly timeouts). fired-up the instance, created a Plone site, and then got the same error.

Ultimately, I blew away everything that was built in eggs ( rm -r ../buildout-cache/eggs/* ) and other things like .installed and the .mr.developer stuff in my buildout root. Then, 'python bootstrap.py' again and re-run the buildout. This has happened often enough that I have a shell script to wipe everything clean. I'm sure there's a better way (tests?) But, it works for me.